# Parameter has no default value, Excel C#

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I have some problem with my code below. I want to insert WSID data from datagridview to my excel file. When I run, there is a problem in my commanddir2.ExecuteNoQuery() and it says Parameter @wsid has no default value. Can anyone help me ?

```
string koneksi = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Dokumen\Alfon\Kerja\BCA\Program\Program-Pengisian-Uang-ATM-BCA-SOY\Program-Pengisian-Uang-ATM-BCA-SOY\bin\x86\Debug\ATM SLA SURABAYA.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES';";


private void InputScheduleSaldoBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < ViewDataSaldoGV.Rows.Count; i++ )
                {

                OleDbConnection kon2 = new OleDbConnection(konekpengisian);
                OleDbCommand commanddir2 = kon2.CreateCommand();
                commanddir2.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [Saldo$] ([WSID]) VALUES (@wsid)";
                commanddir2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wsid", ViewDataSaldoGV.Rows[i].Cells["WSID"].Value);
                textBox1.Text = i.ToString();

                kon2.Open();
                commanddir2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                kon2.Close();

            }

            MessageBox.Show("Data berhasil disimpan");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set DBNull when you have null parameter value

```
commanddir2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wsid", ViewDataSaldoGV.Rows[i].Cells["WSID"].Value)?? DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: I have tried to use your code and it can not be used. It says "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expression can be used as a statement"